# Whats going wrong while assigning used date to User object?

Tags: typescript

I'm not able to set the below array of objects to the User class in TypeScript. `let user: User[] = [{name: 'Naveen', address: [{'city': 'Bangalore'}]}]`;

```
class User {
    private name: string;
    private address: Address[];

    constructor(name: string, address: Address[]) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public set _name(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public get _name() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

class Address {
    private city: string;

    constructor(city: string) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public set _city(city: string) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public get _city() {
        return this.city;
    }
}

let user: User[] = [{name: 'Naveen', address: [{'city': 'Bangalore'}]}];
```

Comment: This question needs a better title.  There is no attached image.

Comment: Thank you, @Amy! Title changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create objects like this.

```
const address = new Address('Bangalore');
let user: User[] = [new User('Naveen', [address])];
```

Comment: Also `let user: User[] = [new User('Naveen', [new Address('Bangalore')])];`